# How convert QString to char correctly when Chinese characters are involved

Tags: qt, encoding, char, qstring

A Qt object bases on Qt4 and runs on CentOS 7.

I get a QString file directory from `getExistingDirectory`. File name contains Chinese characters. Then I use `toLocal8Bit` to convert it to `char`, and the `char` variable occurs messy code.

I tried `QTextCodec` with GBK, big5 and so on, there is no progress.

Comment: Wonder how this would work... there are thousands upon thousands of characters in Chinese, and an 8bit char can only hold as much as 256 and some of them are reserved...

Answer (score 0):

`toLocal8bit` on CentOS likely doesn't support unicode, instead use `toUtf8` which is the ascii compatible unicode encoding.

However whatever will interpret the `char*` will need to know it is in UTF8 otherwise you will still see garbage on the receiving end.